# Kotlin nested for loops to asSequence

Tags: kotlin, code-cleanup

I'm trying to convert my nested for loop to `asSequence` in Kotlin. Here, my goal is to **get and update the value of all my object array** from **another object array with the same key**.

nested for loop:

```
val myFields = getMyFields()
val otherFields = getOtherFields()

for (myField in myFields) { // loop tru the my fields
     for (otherField in otherFields) { // find the same fields
          if (myField.key == otherField.key) { // if the same, update the value
              val updatedMyField = myField.copy(value = otherValue.value)

              myFields[myFields.indexOf(myField)] = updatedMyField // update my field value
              break
           }
      }
}
```

What I've tried:

```
val updatedMyFields = getMyFields().asSequence()
                    .map { myField ->
                        getOtherFields().asSequence()
                            .map { otherField ->
                                if (myField.key == otherField.key) {
                                    return@map otherField.value
                                } else {
                                    return@map ""
                                }
                            }
                            .filter { it?.isNotEmpty() == true }
                            .first()?.map { myField.copy(value = it.toString()) }
                    }
                    .toList()
```

but this does not compile as it will return `List<List<MyField>>`.

I'm just looking for something much cleaner for this.

Comment: Don't you think you should just remove the very last `.toList()`?

Comment: sorry just to add, I also don't think my solution is that much clean, maybe if there's any suggestion on how to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: also shouldn't you be using a `Map` instead of a list?

Comment: Yes I do use a `Map` to swap value via key easily. I'm trying to look for a cleaner approach in my code above (nested for loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments suggest, this would probably be much more efficient with a `Map`.

(More precisely, a map solution would take time proportional to the *sum* of the list lengths, while the nested for loop takes time proportional to their *product* — which gets bigger much faster.)

Here's one way of doing that:

```
val otherFields = getOtherFields().associate{ it.key to it.value }

val myFields = getMyFields().map {
    val otherValue = otherFields[it.key]
    if (otherValue != null) it.copy(value = otherValue) else it
}
```

The first line creates a `Map` from the ‘other fields’ keys to their values.  The rest then uses it to create a new list from ‘my fields’, substituting the values from the ‘other fields’ where present.

I've had to make assumptions about the types &c, since the code in the question is incomplete, but this should do the same.  Obviously, you can change how it merges the values by amending the `it.copy()`.

There are likely to be even simpler and more efficient ways, depending on the surrounding code.  If you expanded it into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — in particular, one that illustrates how you already use a `Map`, as per your comment — we might be able to suggest something better.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks also for the explanation, I'll just adjust this according to my actual needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use asSequence() ? You can go for something like that:

```
 val myFields = getMyFields()
 val otherFields = getOtherFields()

        myFields.forEach{firstField ->
            otherFields.forEach{secondField ->
                if (firstField.key == secondField.key) {
                    myFields[myFields.indexOf(firstField)] = secondField.value
                }
            }
        }
```

This will do the same job than your nested for loop and it's easier to read, to understand and so to maintain than your nested asSequence().

Comment: I don't think nests are easy to read at first, that's why I'm looking for some operators that will reduce or remove it, but, must still be readable.